# Excel: Count Specific Words In Multiple Cells of a Column

Tags: excel, function, formula

I have 200 cells in column A which contain a list of dates:

```
January 14, 2014
January 18, 2014
March 13, 2014
April 15, 2014
June 20, 2014
and so on...
```

What function would I use in order to count the total number of times "January" occurs in column A?

Answer (score 1):

If your data has `Date` format, try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH(A1:A15)=1))
```

Note, if your range contains empty cells, you should use formula, provided @barryhoudini in the comment below.

Comment: This works for me but note that any blanks in A1:A15 would also be counted - to exclude blanks this is one option `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(TEXT(A1:A15,"mmm;;")="Jan"))`

Comment: hm..don't know about that, but it's true:) I'd mention it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A200,"January*")
```